# Magento EE 1.14.2 - Enabling community channel

Tags: magento

I am trying to enable the community channel in Magento EE 1.14.2  In Magento Connect, I get the infamous community channel is not installed error message.

So I thought I would see what is going on via command line:

```
./mage list-channels
Available channels:
```

That looked odd.  So I logged into a 1.14.01 box.

```
./mage list-channels
Available channels:
community: connect20.magentocommerce.com/community
```

That made me feel better, now I see what is wrong, the channel is not there.  I thought I would add the channel:

```
./mage channel-add connect20.magentocommerce.com/community
Error: 
channel-add: Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1
```

This seems to be new to 1.14.2.

Any ideas how to get past this?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I reported this bug to Magento.  They acknowledged it was a bug in 1.14.2 and I was the first to find it :(  They issued a patch to fix this May 15, 2015.

Comment: Do you know the patch name?

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, you should try editting this file,

```
downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
```

and commenting out this line:

```
$this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```